# Inequality proof (strange)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 +d^2 =1$  where $a,b,c,d$ are  positive real numbers, prove that $a+b+c+d-1 \geq 16abcd$

How can I prove the inequality ?

My attempts:

By Cauchy-Schwarz : $ (a+b+c+d)^{2} \leq (a^2 +b^2 +c^2 +d^2 )\cdot (1^2 +1^2 +1^2 + 1^2 ) $ 
Or $ 0\leq a+b+c+d -1 \leq 1 $ .

By AM-GM : $ a^2 + b^2 +c^2 +d^2 \geq 4 \sqrt[4]{(abcd)^2 } $ 
or $ 16abcd \leq 1 $
What can I do from here ?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072899/1-a1-b1-c1-d-geq-abcd-for-a2b2c2d2-1?rq=1) seems related.

Comment: Note:  when $a=b=c=d (= \frac 1 2),$ equality holds

Comment: @Cat master I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please us your attempts.

Comment: I tried AM-GM , Cauchy Swarchz inequality ,...etc , but cannot solve it , can you post the solution and to save time post it in short-terms .

Comment: Show please, how exactly you tried to use AM-GM?

Comment: @Catmaster If you don't show work, it seems like you're just trying to get others to do homework for you. By showing your work, others get the opportunity to potentially show you where you might be going wrong in your attempts or what insights you might need.

Comment: Im having trouble with latex commands .

Comment: Check [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) out for properly formatting math expressions. Learning this for 10 minutes will benefit you for years to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a+b+c+d=4u$, $ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd=6v^2$ and $u^2=tv^2$.

Thus, since $u^2\geq v^2$ it's
$$\sum_{sym}(a-b)^2\geq0,$$ we get $t\geq1$  and since by AM-GM
$$ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd\geq6\sqrt{abcd},$$ it's enough to prove that
$$(a+b+c+d)\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^3}-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2\geq16v^4$$ or
$$2u\sqrt{(4u^2-3v^2)^3}-(4u^2-3v^2)^2\geq v^4$$ or
$$t(4t-3)^3\geq(8t^2-12t+5)^2$$ or
$$(t-1)(48t^2-68t+25)\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?